# How to show current url path in react?

Tags: reactjs

How to show current path in react, when I click automotive menu showing correct and the after I clicked second menu is Electronics showing automotive menu not working.
Can you please check categories component Only.

And I have attached below code and screenshot. could you please check this image.

[image]
App.js:

```
    // import logo from './logo.svg';
    import './App.css';
    import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route,useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
    import CustomerReview from './StoreComponent/CustomerReview';
    import Related from './StoreComponent/Related';
    import Store from './StoreComponent/Store';
    import CategoriesList from './ComponentList/CategoriesList';
    import StoreDetails from './StoreComponent/StoreDetails';
    // import styles from './Owl.theme.min.css';
    import Home from './ComponentList/Home';
    // import Searchbox from './Searchbox';
    // import logo from './logo.svg';
     
    function App() {
      return (
        <BrowserRouter>        
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
              <Home/>
            </Route>
            <Route path="/store/:name/:id" component={Store}>
            <StoreDetails/>
            </Route>
            <Route path="/store/:name/:id" component={Store}>
              <Store/>
            </Route>
            <Route path="/store/:name/:id" component={CustomerReview}>
              <CustomerReview/>
            </Route>
            <Route path="/store/:name/:id" component={Related}>
              <Related/>
            </Route>
            <Route path="/categories/:name/:id" component={CategoriesList}>
              <CategoriesList/>
            </Route>
            
          </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
        )
    }
    
    export default App;

Menu.js

    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { Grid, Image} from 'semantic-ui-react';
    import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
    export default class Menu extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    
        this.state = {
          data: [],
          isLoading: true
        };
      }
     
        async componentDidMount() {
          const requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify({ title: 'React POST Request Example' })
        };
    
        const url = "https://test.app/api/v4/web/categories";
        fetch(url,requestOptions)
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((json) => {
            this.setState({ data: json.categories});
            console.log(json.categories)
          })
          .catch((error) => console.error(error))
          .finally(() => {
            this.setState({ isLoading: false });
          });
      }
    
      render() {
         
        return (
            <Grid className="home-icon">
            <Grid.Row centered doubling  columns={8} mobile>
            {this.state.data.map((x, i) => 
            
          <Grid.Column centered key={i} >       
           <Link to={"categories/"+x.store_name+"/"+x.id}><Image src={x.image} alt=""/></Link>
          <p>{x.store_name}</p>
          </Grid.Column>
           )}
            </Grid.Row>
            </Grid>
        
        );
      }
    };

CategoriesList.jsx

    import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
    import { withRouter, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
    import { Grid, Image, Segment, Card } from 'semantic-ui-react';
    import TopMenuStrip from '../ComponentList/TopMenuStrip';
    import LogoSection from '../ComponentList/LogoSection';
    import Footer from '../ComponentList/Footer';
    import Menu from '../ComponentList/Menu'; 
    import CopyRight from '../ComponentList/CopyRight'; 
    class CategoriesList extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    
        this.state = {
          data: [],
          isLoading: true
        };
      }
    
      async componentDidMount() {
        // console.log(this.props.match.params.id)
        let url_id=this.props.match.params.id;
        console.log('category')
        console.log(url_id)
        const url = 'https://test.app/api/v4/web/list';
        const postBody = {
            category_id: url_id,
          offer_type: "",
        };
        const requestOptions = {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
          body: JSON.stringify(postBody),
          
      };
    
      fetch(url,requestOptions)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((json) => {
          this.setState({ data: json});
          console.log('sasasas')
          console.log(json)
        })
        .catch((error) => console.error(error))
        .finally(() => {
          this.setState({ isLoading: false });
        });
    }
    
      render() {
        if (!this.state.data.stores) {
          return null;
        }
        const ListStores = this.state.data.stores;
        return (
          <Fragment>
                    <TopMenuStrip/>
                <LogoSection/>
                <Menu/>
                <Grid className='store-list'>
            <Grid.Column width={16}>
               <p><span>Stores List</span></p>
            </Grid.Column>
         </Grid>    
          <Grid columns={4} className='all-offers storeList'>
         {ListStores.map((x) => {
             return (
            <Grid.Column>
               <Segment>
                  <Card>
                  <Link to={x.store_url}> <Image src={x.image} alt="" className='collection-img'></Image></Link>
                     <Card.Content>
                     <Link to={x.store_url}> <Card.Header>{x.name}</Card.Header></Link>
                        <Card.Description>
                           {x.store_summary}
                        </Card.Description>
                     </Card.Content>
                     <Card.Content extra>
                        <p className='rewards'><span><img src='/images/rewards.png' alt=''></img></span>Cash rewards upto <span>AED {x.cashback}</span></p>
                        <p className='location'><span><img src='/images/location.png' alt=''></img></span> {x.store_branches[0].store_city} & {x.store_branches[0].store_location}</p>
                     </Card.Content>
                  </Card>
               </Segment>
            </Grid.Column>
         )
        })}
         </Grid>
         <Footer/>
         <CopyRight/>
          </Fragment>
        );
      }
    };
    export default withRouter(CategoriesList);
```

Comment: Looks like you appended part of your path to itself. Can you include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? We can't help fix code we can't see.

Comment: Hi Drew i have attached code. can you help me.

Comment: What does the `store_url ` look like?

Comment: Well, straight off you've really misunderstood how the `Router`, `Switch`, and `Route`'s work, you've 4 routes with the same `path` prop value, and you've specified `component` prop and passed children to the `Route` components. I'll dig deeper on the link issue. Agreed, seems *something* is amiss with the `store_url` property on the `ListStores` elements. Can you post what your state data looks like after it's fetched?

Comment: Store_url woriking fine
Menu.js
<Link to={"categories/"+x.store_name+"/"+x.id}><Image src={x.image} alt=""/></Link>
Data Comes:categories/F&B/15      this url not working when second menu click.

Comment: Ok, what is the value of `x.store_name` when mapping links?

Comment: values comes x.store_name=Automotive,F&B,Electronics and value of  id =13,14,15

Comment: url displayed working http://localhost:3000/categories/Automotive/13
http://localhost:3000/categories/Electronics/14
http://localhost:3000/categories/F&B/15

Comment: I think you can refer https://surajsharma.net/blog/current-url-in-react

Comment: Well, I don't see a way to build an "appended" link with `to={"categories/"+x.store_name+"/"+x.id}` so *from only* the code shared, it looks like maybe `to={x.store_url}` could be the malformed paths. We can't confirm unless you share what your data looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I know this error!

It orrurs when you miss to add a slash `/` in the beginning when writing the path in `to` attribute in `react-router`'s `Link` and `NavLink`. To make it work properly, write instead of:

```
<Link to={"categories/"+x.store_name+"/"+x.id}>
```

this:

```
<Link to={"/categories/"+x.store_name+"/"+x.id}>
```

And even better:

```
<Link to={`/categories/${x.store_name}/${x.id}`>
```

This is ES6 template literals. Looks much better, don't you think? :) Read about this here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

In details: not adding a slash in the path beginning in `to` attribute is a way to say "I want you to add this to the end of my current URL!". Sometimes it is useful, but in your case it turns out to be `/categories/.../categories/...`.